# How to add key id to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have array of objects, which need to add `id` in javascript.

```
function addKey(obj){
 return obj.map(e=>({...e, id:index})
}

var obj=[
  {name: "s1"},
  {name: "s2"}
]


Expected Output

[
  {name: "s1", id:0 },
  {name: "s2", id:1 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

using object.assign u can add key

```
 var obj = [{
     name: 's1'
 }, {
  name: 's2'
  }];

 var result = obj.map(function(el,index) {
 var o = Object.assign({}, el);
 o.id = index;
 return o;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why use `Object.assign` when OP was already using spread syntax? e.g. `{ ...e, id: index }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` property by adding the index of an `Array.prototype.map` callback.

```js
const
  obj = [
    { name: "s1" },
    { name: "s2" }
  ],
  offset = 2;

console.log(obj.map((item, id) => ({ ...item, id: id + offset })));
```

If you want to modify the object in-place (without polluting memory), you can try the following:

```js
const
  obj = [
    { name: "s1" },
    { name: "s2" }
  ],
  offset = 2;

obj.forEach((item, index) => item.id = index + offset)

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: how bout when i want to start the count or the id from a static number like 2

Comment: @d'reaper I added an offset to show how to add it.